# Icons of app can shake and delete app by long press in Iphone's HomeShell, I want to implement this effect.How can I implement is?

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable, shake

Icons of app can shake and delete app by long press in Iphone's HomeShell, I want to implement this effect. I knew the rotateAnimation is like the effect in android. But But using rotateAnimation bringed some problems, such as system performence. I want to do shaking effect on the drawable of ImageView. How can I implement is? Any help is grateful!

Comment: if rotateAnimation is too slow you can create your own custom Drawable class that you later use with iv.setImageDrawable()

Comment: The method of setImageDrawalbe() about ImageView is need call repeatly which can lead to system performance in TV applicaitons. And icons of apps are all of the screen that not olny one icon.

Comment: no, you call setImageDrawable once and somewhere in your custom Drawable class you can call scheduleSelf/invalidateSelf in order to "update" Drawable

Comment: I needed the drawableImage shaking all the time. I use the Rotate of Matrix.But it looks like too mechanical. And it's not the same as the IOS's effect.